# Windows Explorer (windows 10) crashes when rename metadata related to "track number" for FLAC files

Tags: windows, metadata, exif

The title pretty much says it all. I am trying to change the metadata for some FLAC files. I have tried editing via the properties menu and also via the details menu at the right. If I change the track number, windows sometimes accepts it. Other times, it freezes and crashes windows explorer. Unfortunately, the file seems to be permanently corrupted at that point. And any return to the folder results in the crashing. I have absolutely no idea why this is happening. It's a simple tag.

I'm on hour number 3 of this and would appreciate any help!

Comment: What is the size of the file, sometimes any tampering with a big file results in crashing.

Comment: The files are big, but not huge. 80-250 MB

Comment: Try using mp3tag and see if the behavior remains the same.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. MP3TAG seemed to work a lot better. I made several changes at once, clicked save, and they all showed up within a few minutes (I walked away to avoid clicking and freezing things).

I also was able to make some progress by going VERY SLOWLY and letting all changes cycle in the windows explorer - sometimes waiting up to 5 minutes per file.

Comment: Working with a clean version of the data, there was zero lag and MP3TAG was able to edit everything and save it in one go. Coming back to the folder resulted in no lag. When I had made the changes both ways, there was lag returning to the folder. 

Thanks for the solution. It's a shame that the default OS method to edit doesn't work properly.

Comment: Also beware large *filenames*. FLAC files often have long descripiive names that, including folder, exceed 260 characters in the full path.